# We are serving hundres of images through a flask api, is this best practise?

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

We currently have a setup where we serve images through a flask API with Gunicorn. The token and the image name come with the url params. We do that for a whole library of images (up to 500). So on one frontend fetch you will make 500 requests.
What I would like to know if this is a best practise, or if there is a way to serve the whole library at once, with one get request, something like `send_all(images)`?

The problem with our solution is that for every get request you need to make a request and a verification. Which works but if you think that the server gets 500 requests at the same time, and 500 verifications at a time I am not sure.

Thanks a lot in advance. :)

Example Request: 
`http://localhost:5000/image-server&image_name=alpha.png&token="xxx-yyy-zzz"`

Semi-Pseudocode:

```py
@app.route("/image-server", methods=['GET])
def get_image():
    image_name = request.args.get("image_name")
    token = request.args.get("id_token")
    if verify_token(token):
        return send_file(f"{image_name}")
    else:
        return Response(404)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options to reduce the connections required to grab images. Combining images reduce the number of requests and overhead, and are thus important to saving resources of the server, especially for flask which already has questionable scalability. The standard response body should only contain ONE image, so some creativity has to be in play.

**Option 1**

Putting images into a singular graphic then using CSS to modify what part of the graphic is used, and thus saving the need for multiple requests. Downside: there is a ton of work to get every image cropped together seamlessly, and often can't do with client-published images that are retrieved. Typically used for static sprites, and probably wont work at all for you but I thought I'd include it.

**Option 2**

Using Content-Type: Multipart to send multiple images back in multiple boundaries. This is a very true and tried method and is a standard way of transmitting binary data using multiple types in one request. Probably the most difficult but very practical, and a good way to serve responses.

**Option 3**

Compress images server-side as a single body then send them to the client to be unzipped there. I am certain this can be done on the fly, but may use quite a bit of server memory to zip files on the fly. I am unsure about the practicality of this approach or how well this will integrate with a browser client

**Option 4 (probably the one I'd use)**

Send the data as a nice JSON object, one key linking to a list of serialized images. The downside is that in some (actually most) cases serializing images increases the data size by up to 30-50%, which may be even a worse strategy than retrieving each image individually in separate requests. Look at base64 or an alternative form of encoding to do this, and even though the single request will be larger with all the serialized images, the overall need to limit requests to your api for each separate image should be more efficient.

HTTP/2 also may support some sort of resource combining that saves the need for tons of requests, but in this case, probably unusable and should be a footnote.

For the request itself, chain the URLs as query parameters. Be sure to check the number of images a client is requesting and rate limit the endpoint so a client doesn't arbitrarily use every system resource with spoofed and garbage requests. Wasting resources on legitimate clients because of multiple image grabs is the least of your worry if clients abuse the resources arbitrarily.

Example:

```
https://myapi.com/getImages?image_names=name1.png,name2.png,name3.png
```

Comment: Really nice answer, thanks a lot! So what we found out is that websites such as instagram use the onetime token mechanism, so thats why I thought one by one request with token authentication and verification is the way to go. But of course there are multiple ways to Rome :).

Comment: All comes down to server resources and creativity. One per request will always be a viable standard! Have a nice day!